# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:750 return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

Tags: node-modules, yarnpkg, gulp-sass

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:750
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
         ^

Error: Your organization used Device Guard to block this app. Contact your support person for 
more info.
\\?\C:\Users\C5281145\AppData\Roaming\sass-binary\win32-x64-67\binding.node
  at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:750:18)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
  at module.exports (C:\SRM\SRM_Workspace\sr\infonet\src\main\resources\node\node_modules\node- 
  sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> 
  (C:\SRM\SRM_Workspace\sr\infonet\src\main\resources\node\node_modules\node- 
  sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
```

I have tried uninstalling node_modules and then running yarn command 
Tried everything on google..
Nothing worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I've been stuck with this same problem this one whole day. After hours of digging, finally I solved it by updating my PC's Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable file. You may find the download link here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Hope your problem will be solved as well!

Thanks a lot to [Solant@Github](https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui/issues/448#issuecomment-599488732)!

Comment: Wow this helped me get https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer up and running! Thanks for posting!

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht glad to hear that! It'll be nice if you can upvote my answer here so others will consider to try this as well. :)

Comment: Sure! Must've been in a hurry to not having done this already.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while trying to execute this single nodejs script from Windows 10: `const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');`

The solution: to start the command line as an administrator, before issuing the command: `node <yourScript>`